# How to Pin Point Large File eating space in Fedora 18

Tags: linux, disk-usage

I can't determine exactly what file is eating up my disk.

Firstly I used `df` command to list my directories:

```
devtmpfs                 16438304        0  16438304   0% /dev
tmpfs                    16449868        0  16449868   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    16449868  1637676  14812192  10% /run
tmpfs                    16449868        0  16449868   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root  51475068 38443612  10393632  79% /
tmpfs                    16449868      384  16449484   1% /tmp
/dev/sda3                  487652    66874    391082  15% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora-home 889839636 44677452 799937840   6% /home
```

Then I ran `du -h / | grep '[0-9\,]\+G'`.

The problem is I get everything including other directories,
so I need to get specifically find `/dev/mapper/fedora-root` 
but when I try `du -h /dev/mapper/fedora-root | grep '[0-9\,]\+G'` I get no results.

I need to know what's eating up `79%` of directory `/`

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you want a graphical tool, you can install `ncdu`.

Comment: @Panki in these situations I find the dirstat gui's much more effective. qdirstat/kdirstat are my go-to's for seeing big files/folders.

Comment: `du -h --max-depth=1 / | awk '$1 ~ /G/' | sort`, find the next interesting largest dir and then drill down with the same command (replacing `/` with your new target).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My magic command in such situation is :

```
du -m . --max-depth=1 | sort -nr | head -20
```

To use this :

1. `cd` into the top-level directory containing the files eating space. This can be `/` if you have no clue ;-)
2. run `du -m . --max-depth=1 | sort -nr | head -20`. This will list the 20 biggest subdirectories of the current directory, sorted by decreasing size.
3. `cd` into the biggest directory and repeat the `du ...` command until you find the BIG file(s)

Comment: I would consider adding -x to `du` for this question's scenario. This prevents it from crossing filesystem boundaries and so doesn't include the other filesystems on the machine like /home, or any nfs mounts/mounted ISO files etc, all of which presumably OP would want to exclude since they are trying to find something taking up space on a particular filesystem.

Comment: That's an interesting choice of options. Personally, I rather `du -sh */ | sort -nh`. `du -m` would round up everything to at least a megabyte. `du -h` will display sizes with suffixes like `K`, `M`, and `G`. `sort -h` will take these suffixes into account. Chosing `du -s */` instead of `du --max-depth=1 .` allows one to refine the glob. Using `head` discards results that might have taken work add up, so I think it's better to let everything be printed in case the sizes are evenly distributed. Avoiding `sort -r` puts the bigger results closer to the new command line prompt.

Comment: `du -sch * | sort -h | less` is a handy equivalent for `--max-depth=1`

Comment: thanks for this i manage to isolate all directories until i have pinpointed the right location.

Answer (score 10):

[`ncdu`](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) is a great tool for this kind of problem. Here's the corresponding [package](https://fedora.pkgs.org/29/fedora-x86_64/ncdu-1.13-4.fc29.x86_64.rpm.html).

[image]
[image]

You can use `-x` if you want to stay on only one filesystem, without following symlinks. For example, as root:

```
ncdu -x /home
```

It's the command line equivalent of [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com/), [Baobab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Usage_Analyzer) or [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/).

It might take a long time to scan a large folders, but once it's done it should be very fast to find the largest files.

Comment: thank you i used this on my development server it was easy using it, but sadly i cant install it on our production.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a feel for the actual size of the file you can [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) files larger than a specific size.

Eg, to find files larger than 10 MiB:

```
find /mounted/drive -size +10M
```

Or

```
find /mounted/drive -size +10M -exec ls -lh {} +
```

---

Httqm's suggestion is also good if the problem isn't one big file but a large collection of smaller files.  That is use [`du`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html) to show directory totals.  Limiting with `--max-depth` is very useful with large directory trees:

```
du -m some/directory --max-depth=1 | sort -nr | head -20
du some/directory --max-depth=1 | sort -n | tail -21
```

Will break a single directory down into sub-directories, the second of these gives you the total for the directory you're listing as well.

Comment: Instead of `-exec ls ..` you can also use `-ls` for some more info.

Answer (score 5):

Use this command to find out which directories are the largest:

```
du -a / | sort -n -r | head
```

Comment: I often use `du -h | sort -h | less`.  Or leave out the `less`, because the largest directories will be at the end of the output.  And the rest are there in the scrollback if you want them.  Or use `du -sch *`.